# Setting up WebApplication host in .NET6 Console App leads to 404 response

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-6.0

I have the below code that runs successfully, receives Http requests but returns 404.
I created a .NET Console App and installed Microsoft.AspNetCore.App package.
I see the WebApplication is receiving the requests but always responds with 404.

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;

using AppHostTest;

var testBuilder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(new WebApplicationOptions ());
testBuilder.Services.AddRazorPages();
testBuilder.Services.AddTransient<IVehicle, Car>();

var testapp = testBuilder.Build();
testapp.UseHttpsRedirection();
testapp.UseStaticFiles();
testapp.UseRouting();
testapp.UseAuthorization();
testapp.MapRazorPages();
testapp.Run();
```

Even though the above code looks exactly same as to what you get when you scaffold a project using WebApplication template, the behaviour is not the same.

Any help with understanding what is wrong with above setup would be highly appreciated.

I tried installing Microsoft.AspNetCode.Mvc package and adding AddMvc() to services and UseMvc() on testapp but did not work and behaviour remains the same.

[image]

Update 1:

I see the WebApplicationBuilder created by scaffolded version populates the WebRootFileProvider as CompositeFileProvider as WebRootPath as wwwroot.

[image]

whereas, the WebApplicationBuilder created by ConsoleApp populates the WebRootFileProvider as NullFileProvider and WebRootPath as null.
[image]

Comment: Do you have an `Index` page in the first place? A scaffolder project doesn't contain just `Program.cs`

Comment: Yes, I do which is a Razor page. Also, because this in a console app, there is no launch.json.

Comment: I notice one difference when comparing the WebApplicationBuilder returned in both project setups. The scaffolded one populates the Environment.WebRootPath points to wwwroot folder where as in the console app this path is NULL. –

Comment: Post your code as text, not images. Images can't be compiled, tested or run

Comment: Code submitted is in the question. That's all I am testing but from Console App. I have mentioned the package that I had installed for adding support for AspNetCore in console app.

Answer (score 1):

If you'd like to create an ASP.NET Core Razor Pages web app from *Console App* template, you can try:

*In .csproj file, specify and use `Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web` for project, like below.*

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">
```

*then add required services and middleware components in `Program.cs` file as you did*

```
var testBuilder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(new WebApplicationOptions());
testBuilder.Services.AddRazorPages();
//testBuilder.Services.AddTransient<IVehicle, Car>();

var testapp = testBuilder.Build();
testapp.UseHttpsRedirection();
testapp.UseStaticFiles();
testapp.UseRouting();
testapp.UseAuthorization();
testapp.MapRazorPages();
testapp.Run();
```

*and then add Pages folder and razor page as below*

[image]

*Index.cshtml*

```
@page
@model AppHostTest.Pages.IndexModel
@{
}

<h1>hello world</h1>
```

Test Result

[image]

Comment: yes, it worked by targeting the SDK.Web. Does this mean there is some under-the-hood magic happening. After re-targeting the SDK, I ran into a "duplicate content" build error arising from CheckDuplicate section in .targets file. I removed the wwwroot folder and added it back and it solved the issue. Any idea what is the tight dependency on the SDK to make the host/mvc/routing/content or endpoint discovery work? (unsure what exactly was not working)

Comment: `Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web`  includes additional functionalities and configurations specific to web development, which would add references to necessary packagesand set up default configurations for web hosting and deployment.